# Geom_line producing vertical lines with grouping

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyverse

I am working on visualizing data (3-years, small timeframe but line graph is the preferred visualization) using geom_line(), but when I do, I get vertical lines in the plot, rather than an actual line graph. I am trying to group on type.

```
country_totals %>%
  ggplot(aes(year, value, color = type, group = type)) + 
  geom_line() +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = comma)
```

[image: Here is the output graph]

Comment: Did you try `group = 1`?

Comment: Can you post the data (or part of it)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have several countries and you want the x axis to be years, shouldn't you group by year and type first?

```r
country_totals %>% 
  group_by(year, type) %>%
  summarize(value = sum(value)) %>%
  ...
```

Comment: Close! I grouped by year and type and was able to get it to work/ Thank you, Julian!

Answer (score 0):

This is because your date format is not correct. Instead of it understanding it as d-M-Y, it is understanding it as M-d-Y, so you have many values for each months but not days in between.
Try reformating your date:
`df$Date <-as.Date(paste(df$Year, df$Momnth, 01), "%Y %m %d")`